# How can I make my data numeral, so I can visualize them via matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

So i have this df, the columns that im intrested in visualizing

later with matplotlib are the 'incident_date', 'fatalities'. I want to create two diagrams. The one will display the number of the incidents with injuries (the column named 'fatalities' says whether it was a fatal accident, or just one with injuries or neither), the other will display the dates with the most deaths. So, in order to do those, I need somehow to turn the data in the 'fatalities' column into numeral ones.

[This is my df's head, so you get an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIQJw.png)

Comment: Please provide your data frame in text, preferably with constructor as well `df.to_dict()`.

Answer (score -1):

I created dummy data based on picture you provided

```
data = {'incident_date':['1-Mar-20','1-Mar-20','3-Mar-20','3-Mar-20','3-Mar-20','5-Mar-20','6-Mar-20','7-Mar-20','7-Mar-20'] \
        ,'fatalities':['Fatal','Fatal','Injuries','Injuries','Neither','Fatal','Fatal','Fatal','Fatal'] \
        , 'conclusion_number':[1,1,3,23,23,34,23,24,123]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

All you need is to do a group by incident_data and fatalities and you will get the numerical values for that particular date and that particular incident.

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['incident_date','fatalities'],as_index=False)['conclusion_number'].count()
df_grp.rename({'conclusion_number':'counts'},inplace=True, axis=1)
```

The Output of above looks like this.

[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1UA6.png)

Once you get counts column you can perform your matplot diagrams.

Let me know if you need help with diagrams as well